# System.QueryException while System.debug() for a deserialized Object

Tags: apex, rest-api, json, related-list, deserialize

My question is similar to [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/174832/for-an-sobject-parameter-of-an-apex-rest-api-how-can-you-pass-in-nested-related). I'm trying to create a Case and process few child task records from a REST API Call.

REST API Endpoint POC:

[image]

But when I executed this as below, I get error **System.QueryException: Aggregate query has too many rows for direct assignment, use FOR loop\n\nExternal entry point** in above highlighted line which is a System.debug(). If I remove the debug line no errors.

[image]

Also note it doesn't go inside the for loop. Any ideas how to deserialize this and create the SObject with it's related records? Is it not possible to follow this approach to receive related records?

Any thoughts/suggestions are much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error occurs because the JSON doesn't include the `done` property, or it is set to false.

```
//Note "done": false
String s = '{"attributes":{"type":"Case"},"Subject":"Demo","Tasks":{"size":"1","done":false,"records":[{"attributes":{"type":"Task"},"Subject":"Demo"}]}}';
Case c = (Case)JSON.deserialize(s, Case.class);
System.debug(c);
// Exception thrown here
System.debug(''+c.Tasks);
```

---

```
// Runs to completion
//Note "done": true
String s = '{"attributes":{"type":"Case"},"Subject":"Demo","Tasks":{"size":"1","done":true,"records":[{"attributes":{"type":"Task"},"Subject":"Demo"}]}}';
Case c = (Case)JSON.deserialize(s, Case.class);
System.debug(c);
System.debug(''+c.Tasks);
```

Make sure that the `size` and `done` properties are set correctly, or you can expect this type of exception if you do certain things, such as trying to `toString` or assigning the property to a `List<Task>`.

Comment: Thank you @sfdcfox!